# wagtailimages.0016... migration error: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for wagtailimages_rendition

Tags: wagtail

While running the migrations from Wagtail 1.7 to 1.8 I'm getting the following migration error:

```
 Applying wagtailimages.0016_deprecate_rendition_filter_relation...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "djangoware/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 532, in database_forwards
    getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 329, in alter_unique_together
    self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 83, in _delete_composed_index
    return super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self)._delete_composed_index(model, fields, *args)
  File "/Users/nicklo/.virtualenvs/theproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 358, in _delete_composed_index
    ", ".join(columns),
ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for wagtailimages_rendition(image_id, filter_id, focal_point_key)
```

It's extremely likely that this isn't a clean migration as while trying to do a gradual upgrade from 1.6.1 to 1.6.3 to 1.7 and then to 1.8 a 3rd party app install attempted to jump forward to 1.8 so I had to try and clean the migration and try again.

I'm quite happy to try and fix this manually via SQL if needed. The current state of the wagtailimages_rendition table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `wagtailimages_rendition` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `focal_point_key` varchar(17) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `filter_spec2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filter_spec` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_f33175e6` (`image_id`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_0a317463` (`filter_id`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_58c64917` (`filter_spec`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=352 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And I note another project I have running on Wagtail 1.8 has the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `wagtailimages_rendition` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `focal_point_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_spec` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_image_id_323c8fe0_uniq` (`image_id`,`filter_spec`,`focal_point_key`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rend_filter_id_7fc52567_fk_wagtailimages_filter_id` (`filter_id`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_58c64917` (`filter_spec`),
  KEY `wagtailimages_rendition_f33175e6` (`image_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wagtailimages_rend_filter_id_7fc52567_fk_wagtailimages_filter_id` FOREIGN KEY (`filter_id`) REFERENCES `wagtailimages_filter` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wagtailimages_rendit_image_id_3e1fd774_fk_wagtailimages_image_id` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `wagtailimages_image` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=272 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Help indicating the constraint alterations I need to do via SQL would likely be enough to solve the problem but any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you were affected by this bug in Wagtail 1.8: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3256

This would have caused migration 0016 to fail part-way through the operation:

```
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='rendition',
        unique_together=set([('image', 'filter_spec', 'focal_point_key')]),
    ),
```

which involves dropping a unique constraint on (image_id, filter_id, focal_point_key) and creating a new one on (image_id, filter_spec, focal_point_key). The latter fails because it exceeds MySQL's length limit on some configurations.

To fix it, ensure you have Wagtail 1.8.1 installed (it looks like you have, since it's successfully reduced the length of `focal_point_key` to 17 chars). Then, to put the database state back to the correct state prior to migration 0016, run:

```
ALTER TABLE wagtailimages_rendition ADD UNIQUE KEY wagtailimages_rendition_image_id_uniq (image_id, filter_id, focal_point_key);
```

Now `manage.py migrate` should hopefully complete the remaining migrations.

Comment: I've not yet tested your answer as In order to maintain progress on the project I'd cheated and recreated the table from the working Wagtail project via SQL then faked 0016_deprecate_rendition_filter_relation but it sounds exactly like the issue I had so I'm marking it as answered. Many thanks for the feedback.